# sklearn error: "X and y have incompatible shapes."

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

New to scikit learn.  I'm trying to fit a logistic regression to some made up data but I get the error "X and y have incompatible shapes. X has 1 samples, but y has 6."

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Create a sample dataframe
data = [['Age', 'ZepplinFan'], [13 , 0], [40, 1], [25, 0], [55, 0], [51, 1], [58, 1]]
columns=data.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

# Fit Logistic Regression
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X=df.Age.values, y = df.ZepplinFan)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24935154/2146894) indicates that I need to somehow reshape df.Age.values to (n_samples, 1).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape matters yes. One way to do it, is pass columns like

```
In [24]: lr.fit(df[['Age']], df['ZepplinFan'])
Out[24]:
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001)
```

If you want to explicitly pass values then you could

```
In [25]: lr.fit(df[['Age']].values, df['ZepplinFan'].values)
Out[25]:
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001)
```

Or you could `newaxis` to you existing syntax like

```
In [26]: lr.fit(df.Age.values[:,np.newaxis], df.ZepplinFan.values)
Out[26]:
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001)
```